# Div scrolling on custom selection of a list item that is hidden below scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview

[image: Custom Control]

I am working on a custom control which renders a textbox and below it an ordered list. Let me come to the point directly, in textbox if a user presses up or down, it iterates through the listitems giving each item a class selecting (dotted) and removing the class selecting from the previous item. Now the problem is, when the selecting class is assigned to the last item visible on the page, everything is fine till then, but after that when a user presses down button, the selecting class is assigned to an item that is not visible on the page, the div has to be scrolled down now. Now, I am out of ideas how to scroll down the div at this specific point, and viceversa. I mean how to scroll it down, but what should trigger this scrolling down.

I should also mention that the list(ol) is contained in a div which has a max-height and overflow auto. And I will have to scroll THIS div upto the item i want to scroll down/up to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('your-parent-element').scrollTop($('your-item').scrollTop());
```

Where your-parent-element is the parent list and 'your-item' is that element which is not displaying.

Comment: Oh i forgot to mention one thing, actually the list is contained in a div, and the div is scrollable, but the item I am selecting is inside my list. I guess the above snippet would work if I had made my list scrollable instead of keeping it inside a scrollable div.

Comment: Ok, lets debug it then. What comes when you alert($('your-item').scrollTop())? Lets say it comes as 100. And then what happens when you set that value to the div, like $('your-parent-element').scrollTop(100)?

Comment: well, I checked it in debug, my items scrolltop is coming out 0

Comment: ok, now lets try it with offset. Try something like $('your-parent-element').scrollTop($('your-item').offset().top); If it gives some value greater than 0, then you can play with it.

Comment: thanks for giving the idea of offset, didnt cross my mind. It worked for me like this 

    $('#listParent').scrollTop($('li.selecting').offset().top - $('#listParent').height() + 100)

Comment: now it is acting strange, I am scrolling on every item "selecting" and although the selected item is visible but now the div is scrolled up and down over and over again

Comment: May be because $('li.selecting') is giving the array of items. So first try to choose the correct item from the array. And also check for the scrollTop function being called multiple times. I mean put some console.log or alert and check if it is being called multiple times.

Comment: i have removed all selecting before adding it to an item, the problem is that it is calling scrollTop for every item, even if it is visible of not!

Comment: I think the problem is where this line $('#listParent').scrollTop($('li.selecting').offset().top - $('#listParent').height() + 100)  is being called from. You should check it there too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26155/discussion-between-taha-rehman-siddiqui-and-gaurav)